# $K$ be a field of characteristic $p$, then is the map $x \to x^p$ injective?

Tags: field-theory

Suppose $K$ is a field of characteristic $p>0$. Then is the map $x \to x^p$ injective? I think if $K$ is finite, then it is true. But what will happen in case of arbitrary field?

Edit: Yes, It has to be since the morphism from field is always injective.
The ideals of $K$ has to be trivial

Comment: It's a homomorphism (Frobenius homomorphism) and field homomorphisms are always injective.

Comment: You say that morphisms from fields are either zero or injective, this is wrong - they are always injective. Ring homomorphisms must preserve $1$.

Answer (score 4):

Here is an explicit simple argument for injectivity, the known one. Let $p$ be the characteristic and let $F$ be the ([Frobenius morphism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frobenius_endomorphism)) map $x\to x^p$. Assume that for some $x,y\in K$ we have $Fx=Fy$, i.e. $x^p=y^p$. Then:
$$
0=x^p-y^p=(x-y)^p\ ,
$$
so $(x-y)=0$ since $K$ is a field, so $x=y$. This concludes the injectivity of $F$.

---

We have used the binomial theorem, and the fact that for $k$ between $1$ and $(p-1)$ in the binomial coefficient
$$\binom pk=\frac{p(p-1)\dots(p-k+1)}{k(k-1)\dots 1}\in\Bbb Z$$
the prime $p$ from the numerator is not "simplified" by some (same) factor from the denominator, so it is zero modulo $p$.

Comment: Looking at this argument, one is naturally tempted to mention this the [freshman's dream](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Freshman%27s_dream).

Answer (score 0):

Qi Zhu is right, I'm just adding some details.
We now show $x \to x^p$ is a field homomorphism as follows.
Note that the only nontrivial part of the proof is that $(x+y)^p = x^p + y^p$ since the field is of characteristic $p$, we're through.